# SQS Message getting deleted when exception occurs while doing business logic in Consumer

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We want to handle retry logic in sqs. If our application gets exception while doing business logic the message should be remain in the queue after visibilityTimeOut. The message should be moved to deadLetterQueue only after retry count=10.

But in our application the message getting deleted if we get an exception in the code.

The below is the spring xml configurations

```
<bean id="messageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${aws.eventNotificationQueue}" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="eventNotificationListener" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value = "5000"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value = "2"/>
</bean>
```

Consumer program

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    try {
        message = null;//This is to check exception case 
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        String sqsMsg = textMessage.getText();
        notificatinFlag = eventNotificationService.handleEventNotification(sqsMsg);
        message.acknowledge();

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Exception while consuming message"+ e)
    }
```

Please help me to sort this issue.

Comment: are you seeing the log message for the messages that are getting deleted?

Comment: No  i am not seeing in the log. but the message is not available in queue.

Comment: The message is getting deleted due to spring jms configurations.Added the below configuration not to delete the message in the case of exception.<beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"> But AWS SQSConnection not accepting sessionTransacted="true". i am getting "trying to recover. Cause: SQSSession does not support transacted". Please suggest me any workaround to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you find how to solve it ?